# How to check if my BIOS is SSD compatible?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios

I have a [Toshiba L850-13R](http://www.toshiba.hu/discontinued-products/satellite-l850-13r/) laptop and I want to upgrade from a HDD to a SSD. However I read on forums that there could be problems where the BIOS could not see the newly bought SSD.

How can I check if my BIOS is compatible with a SSD ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is just silly. Simple SATA based SSD drives uses SATA, which is a standard. It will work.
So from a BIOS side, there is no problem.

But maybe it uses some special HDD enclosure or some other fitting that people ignored.
I can't think of anything else. Try taking it apart and check. If it's a standard SATA drive, it will work.

Comment: You may run into issues with PCI-E flash "drives" and "PATA" SSDs.  If it has a standard SATA connector (and you aren't trying to put an mSATA drive into a non-mSATA slot) you should have no issue.

Comment: @ultrasawblade - Is there even a PATA SSD?

Comment: I haven't actually bought one yet but they connect via Mini-PCIe and I guess show up as an IDE drive.  To add storage to a laptop if you don't have an mSATA and only have miniPCIe slots.  I'm hoping, anyway.  Various well known auction sites have them.